# Is there an inline nil check for optional string values in swift while unwrapping?

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error for the below code:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

```
let fullName = "\(passenger.lastName!), \(passenger.firstName!) \(passenger.middleName!)"
```

I'm trying to unwrap these optional values such that I can still get a fullName values from each name part.

I understand that I can put each of these in a separate variable, and then check for "nil" before combining into the final "fullName" variable, but is there an easier way to do this so that I can keep it a one-liner? I have similar code all over the place and am hoping to not have to do nil checks everywhere.

Comment: What would you like the result to be if one of those properties is `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an inline nil check as such, but in certain situations (like in your example) you can provide a default value inline, like so:

```
let fullName = "\(passenger.lastName ?? "Bacon"), \(passenger.firstName ?? "Kevin") \(passenger.middleName ?? "Norwood")"
```

(Probably more sensible to use `""` instead of Kevin Bacon though...)

Comment: The problem with this, assuming you replace "Kevin" and "Bacon" with "", is that if either the first or last name is nil, you end up with a superfluous comma in the result.

Comment: @HangarRash For sure. Ultimately, `fullName` should be a computed property so the unwrap logic only has to be written once.

Comment: That's true... I didn't consider that. In my particular scenario, the extra commas were not a big deal, but this is a good point!

Answer (score 1):

The exlamation mark in passenger.firstName! means "I know it is optional, but I can guarantee one hundred thousand percent that it is not nil at runtime. If it is nil, then dear Mr. Swift, please crash my program." And Swift follows your wishes.

Instead you write

```
if let lastName = passenger.lastName, firstName = passenger.firstName {
    let fullName = "\(lastName), \(firstName)"
} else {
    // Whatever you do to handle the error
}
```

or

```
guard let lastName = passenger.lastName, firstName = passenger.firstName else {
    // Whatever you do to handle the error
    // return, break, etc. to exit the current scope
}
let fullName = "\(lastName), \(firstName)"
```

An alternative is to use passenger.lastName ?? "" which gives you lastName if it is not nil, or an empty string otherwise. That gives you the wrong result if the person is an artist named Sting or Prince because you don't want a comma. So decide carefully what you want in each case and write a bit more code once to get the right result once and for all.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue with the OP's wishes and the problem with the other answers - the hanging comma.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution is to add a computed property to `Optional` that returns an empty string if the value is nil

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var emptyIfNil: String {
        if case Optional.some(let wrapped) = self {
            wrapped
        } else {
            ""
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
let fullName = "\(passenger.lastName.emptyIfNil), \(passenger.firstName.emptyIfNil) \(passenger.middleName.emptyIfNil)"
```

Or if the replacement string should be dynamic then it could be a function instead

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func replaceNil(with string: String = "") -> String {
        if case Optional.some(let wrapped) = self {
            wrapped
        } else {
            string
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
let fullName = "\(passenger.lastName.replaceNil()), \(passenger.firstName.replaceNil()) \(passenger.middleName.replaceNil(with: "X"))"
```

Comment: I like the `replaceNil(with:)` idea, but your solution will have a "hanging comma" if the first name is blank.

Comment: I saw that when testing my code but as I see it this question is about how to handle optional values and unwrapping only so I deliberately ignored that part

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to put your items into an array, then use `compactMap` and `joined(separator:)`

sample code:

```
let array = ["one", nil, "three", nil, "five"]
let string = array.compactMap{$0}.joined(separator: ", ")
print(string)
```

That outputs

> one, three, five

Or, if you want to use that approach with a struct like yours:

```
struct Passenger: CustomStringConvertible {
    let lastName: String?
    let middleName: String?
    let firstName: String?

    var description: String {
        return [lastName, middleName, firstName].compactMap{$0}.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}

var aPassenger = Passenger(lastName: "Doe", middleName: nil, firstName: "Jane")
print ("\'\(aPassenger.description)'")

aPassenger = Passenger(lastName: "Public", middleName: "Q.", firstName: "John")
print ("\'\(aPassenger.description)'")
```

That outputs:

> 'Doe, Jane'
>
> 'Public, Q., John'

### Edit:

As pointed out, my solution puts commas between every part of the passenger's names. That's not quite what the OP asked for. I will leave my answer because it works well in cases where you DO want to filter out nils and add a separator between non-nil items in an array.

Comment: Except the OP's desired output does not have a command between first and middle name. This answer only works if every value is only separated by a common separator.

Comment: Oh rats. I should have looked more carefully at the sample data.